# Redirigir Carpeta a subdominio

Tags: html, web, .htaccess, dominio

estoy tratando de redireccionar un subdominio a una carpeta dentro de mi htdocs este es el codigo de mi htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?projectzerorp.com$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress/$1
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?projectzerorp.com$
 RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

El codigo en si funciona bien, ya que me redirige el dominio a la pagina de wordpress principal, pero quiero vincular el subdominio foro.projectzerorp.com con la carpeta flarum que voy a pasar a continuacion

Aqui mi arbol de directorios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro de flarum/public

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado muchas maneras de como hacer que el subdominio muestre el flarum bien, buscando por google y tal, pero no encuentro solucion a mi problema, alguna ayuda?

Muchas gracias por leerme.